# MVC return populated model from view after form submission

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My Model:

```
 public class SendFileDeviceViewModel
  {
    public SendFileDeviceViewModel()
    {
      PolicyList = new List<SendFileDevicePoliciesViewModel>();
    }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string ManagementGroupName { get; set; }
    public int ManagementGroupId { get; set; }
    public bool ReloadConfiguration { get; set; }
    public bool ImmediateSend { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeToSend { get; set; }
    public List<SendFileDevicePoliciesViewModel> PolicyList { get; set; }
  }
  public class SendFileDevicePoliciesViewModel
  {
    public int PackageTemplateId { get; set; }
    public string PolicyName { get; set; }
    public string PolicyType { get; set; }
    public string DefinedAt { get; set; }
    public bool ResendPolicy { get; set; }
  }
```

My View:

```
<h2>Send files to a Device @Model.DeviceName</h2>
  <h3>Reload configuration settings</h3>
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ReloadConfiguration) @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReloadConfiguration)
  <h3>Select the policies to reload</h3>
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DeviceId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ManagementGroupId)

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    if (Model.PolicyList.Count() > 0)
    {
    <table>
      <caption>
        Policies available for this device</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">
            &nbsp;
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            Policy Name
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            Policy Type
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            Defined At
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach (var policies in Model.PolicyList)
        {
          <tr>
            @*<td>@Html.CheckBox("PackageTemplateId", new { value = policies.PackageTemplateId })</td>*@
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => policies.ResendPolicy)</td>
            <td>@policies.PolicyName</td>
            <td>@policies.PolicyType</td>
            <td>@policies.DefinedAt</td>
          </tr>
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
    }

    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImmediateSend)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ImmediateSend)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TimeToSend)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TimeToSend)
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Send files" /></p>
```

My issue is when retrieving model from controller the PolicyList is always empty. Am I missing somethign simple here?

Comment: Where is the controller code to populate `PolicyList`?

Comment: In my controller :) I did'nt include it because the view is populated fine, its the return Im concerned with. If its relevant I can post but I dont see how it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two problems:

Your first problem is that you are resetting your list in your constructor, so when the form is posted and the model binder instantiates an instance of your model, you're re-setting the list. Change it to do a coalesce to only re-assign if the list is `null`:

```
public SendFileDeviceViewModel()
{
    PolicyList = PolicyList ?? new List<SendFileDevicePoliciesViewModel>();
}
```

Your next problem is your `foreach`. In order to index the `name` attribute correctly (so the model binder can do it's stuff), you need to use a `for` loop. Also, keep the Id in a `HiddenFor`.

Try this in place of your `foreach`:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PolicyList.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PolicyList[i].PackageTemplateId)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PolicyList[i].ResendPolicy)
        </td>
        <td>@Model.PolicyList[i].PolicyName</td>
        <td>@Model.PolicyList[i].PolicyType</td>
        <td>@Model.PolicyList[i].DefinedAt</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: @DavidB No problems, glad I could help :)

Comment: unfortunately my list is still empty, any ideas?

Comment: @DavidB Hmm, when debugging are the rest of your model values there?

Comment: Yeah everythign else is there, but my list count = 0

Comment: actually no they are not, they revery to default  values -sorry about that.

Comment: @DavidB Hmmm that suggests something on your view isn't quite right (or you have duplicate items for the same Model item). Can you post your newly updated view?

Comment: I use MEF to add controllers in a plug in fashion, and for some reason this view isnt being outputted to the correct oocation so it was runnign an old one. My apologies. Ill get it sorted and give it another try

Comment: I shut down VS, deleted bin and obj, clean and rebuild and that did the trick. The old view was hanging around for some reason. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is because you didn't respect the [`naming convention`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) of your input fields. You should replace the `foreach` loop in the view with a `for` loop or a custom editor template:

```
<tbody>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.PolicyList.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.PolicyList[i].ResendPolicy)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PolicyList[i].PolicyName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PolicyList[i].PolicyType)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PolicyList[i].DefinedAt)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Also now only the `ResendPolicy` property will be bound because that's the only one that has a corresponding input field (a checkbox in your case). If you want to bind the others as well you might need to include corresponding hidden fields:

```
<tbody>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.PolicyList.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PolicyList[i].PackageTemplateId)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.PolicyList[i].ResendPolicy)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PolicyList[i].PolicyName)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PolicyList[i].PolicyName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PolicyList[i].PolicyType)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PolicyList[i].PolicyType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PolicyList[i].DefinedAt)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PolicyList[i].DefinedAt)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```